# How is the following Rails model should look like in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, migration, associations, sequel

I've the following two models:

```
class Dispute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accuser,    class_name: 'User', optional: true
  belongs_to :defendant,  class_name: 'User', optional: true
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here's the migration for `Dispute`:

```
class CreateDisputes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :disputes do |t|
      t.references :accuser
      t.references :defendant
    end
  end
end
```

This is how they behave in Rails:

```
Dispute.first.accuser
# => <# User>
Dispute.first.defendant
# => <# User>
```

In Sequel, I'm supposed [to use `many_to_one`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html#label-many_to_one), but does that mean that Sequel `User` model should have a corresponding `one_to_many`? Can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table(:disputes) do
      primary_key :id
      foreign_key :accuser_id, :users
      foreign_key :defendant_id, :users
    end
  end
end

class Dispute < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :accuser, :class=>:User
  many_to_one :defendant, :class=>:User
end
```